# swift: UITextField does not have a member named text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift

I have @IBAction on event Editing Did Begin

```
@IBAction func saveCurrentTextField(sender: UITextField) {

    let myTextField : UITextField = sender as UITextField
    myClass.saveMyTextField(myTextField)

}
```

And then I have button with @IBAction on event Touch Up Inside

```
@IBAction func saveValueOfThoseTextField(sender: UIButton) {

    println("Those textField = \(myClass.thoseTextField)")
    let text : String = myClass.thoseTextField.text

}
```

println return:

```
UITextField: 0xb289b80; frame = (165 15; 40 30); text = '15'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = NSArray: 0xb28f730>; layer = CALayer: 0xb289cc0
```

But on string `let text : String = myClass.thoseTextField.text` I get error: `UITextField does not have a member named text`

Comment: how do you declare that textfield property/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
let text : String = myClass.thoseTextField!.text
```

The textfield you are referencing is likely an IBOutlet, and will be optional.

Comment: Properties marked with `@IBOutlet` are *implicitly unwrapped* optionals, therefore unwrapping with `!` should not be necessary.

Comment: It depends how he declared it. If he declared it as optional, he would have to unwrap it. If he didn't, it should have a text property, which he doesn't seem to.

Comment: The source textField is the textField on custom cell: @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField

Comment: And in class: var thoseTextField : UITextField? = nil

Comment: [This is a good writeup](http://makeapppie.com/tag/does-not-have-a-member-named/) of this issue along with specifics from the Apple documentation about how this is an optional and needs to be unwrapped. You can see in the documentation that it is declared as an optional `Declaration SWIFT var text: String?`

Answer (score 2):

@IBOutlet var txt_RegNumber: [UITextField]!

you might have like this just remove []
because takes array as default